# Get sum of some arrays' elements C++

Tags: c++, arrays

How could I possibly get sum of elements between two given points in array if given:

n - Array length

m - Number of questions about array

a[n] - array numbers

m questions in format x y

> **Example**
>
> ***Input***
>
> 3 3
>
> -1 2 0
>
> 3 3
>
> 1 3
>
> 1 2
>
> ***Output***
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> 1

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,m,x,y;
    cin>>n>>m;
    int a [n];
    int s [m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m ; i++){
        cin>>x>>y;
        if(x == y){
            s[i] = a[x-1];
            continue;
        }
        s[i] =  accumulate(a + x - 1, a + y,0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        cout<<s[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

***This is not a school homework, just a task from internet - it will be run on test server using [Standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) for input and result check.***

I need this program to be run in less than 0.2 seconds with:

0 < n,m <= 50000

-1000 <= a[i] <= 1000

1<=x<=y<=n

How can I make it run more time efficiently?

Comment: Outputting in the calculation loop slows you down.

Comment: then how can i do this without it? + time isn't the main problem its result.

Comment: And... what's wrong with your code?

Comment: How big is `n` and `m`?

Comment: oh Sorry forgot to say, they are 0<N,M<=50000. Edited question

Comment: Well, given that the specification of the problem (input size and execution time limit) are exactly the ones you find in algorithmic competions and programming courses, where you submit the program to an automatic judge server, it's hard to think that this is not some kind of homework/assignment...

Comment: IT is not they are only random tasks in online test servers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of time can be spent in the `accummulate` function when `n` and `m` are large.

Let's use following data in our example:

```
const int n = 10;

int a[n] = {6, 1, 3, 2, 9, 8, 7, 2, 0, 1};
```

Let's create an auxiliary array and fill it with sums from `a[0]` to `a[i]` for each `i`. This can be made in a single loop.

```
int s[n+1];

void precalculate() {
    s[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        s[i+1] = s[i] + a[i];
    }   
}
```

Then the whole `accummulate` function collapses to a single subtraction:

```
int accummulate(int i, int j) {
    return s[j] - s[i-1];
}
```

It works well as it can be easily demonstrated:

```
int main() {
    precalculate();
    assert(accummulate(1, 1) == 6);
    assert(accummulate(10, 10) == 1);
    assert(accummulate(1, 10) == 39);
    return 0;
}
```